# How to get Javascript Variable Content in to a Velocity variable?

Tags: java, velocity

I am using Polarion, which uses Velocity Template and thus javascript and html. A lot of the details don't really matter but I use

```
#set($currentId = "this.id")
console.log($currentId)
activityBox.innerHTML += ${currentId};
```

Which logs and correctly appends the right Id of the div im on right now.
However if I try to invoke a function from my Java API it doesn't properly evaluate the variable $currentId

```
#set($currentWorkitem = $trackerProject.getWorkItem($!{currentId}))
console.log("$currentWorkitem")
```

it does call the function, but with the wrong argument. It uses "this.id" instead of the actual Id.

I know this most likely has something to do with the order in which velocity and javascript are evaluated, but I don't know if I can fix this. How can I properly put the value of a javascript expression inside my velocity variable?

Comment: Did you mean `console.log($currentWorkitem)` instead of `console.log("$currentWorkitem")`? What does `getWorkItem` return?

Comment: getWorkItem returns some Java Object; console.log($currentWorkitem) doesn't work for some reason (I'm assuming because its neither a String nor a JS Object?)

Comment: So what is that Java object supposed to do? What string do you expect velocity to render into the JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your very first line which is wrong. You said it yourself, it's an evaluation order problem. `this.id` is unknown at the time velocity is evaluated, since Velocity rendering happens on the server, before Javascript evaluation in the browser.

Velocity does *generate* code (HTML code or Javascript code) which is *transmitted* over the network to your browser, which *interprets* this code.

You can write `let someJavascriptVar = "${someVelocityVar}"` because the browser will see `let someJavascriptVar = "Hello there".

You cannot do the opposite, because the browser has not even received the Javascript code he's supposed to run, how would any Javascript variable mean something at this point?

What you *can* do from Javascript is make another request to the server (using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/AJAX) for instance), let Velocity on the server generate a new content, wait for this content in the browser (typically asynchronously using the [*fetch* API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)), then use the values sent back from the server.

In a nutshell, you need a new round-trip between the client and the server.

Comment: So there is no way of really using data from javascript for my velocity function? Are there any work-arounds?

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Yes thank you, now I understand